# Best way to remove collision of names in c++

Tags: c++, visual-c++, windows-7, winapi

I just upgraded from WinXP to Seven and I had to add the Windows SDK to my project to make it compile.

So far so good but my second project hit a snag, 'PlayerState' is used in my project as a class and in the Windows SDK (effects.h) as an enum and this obviously generates an error (error C2011: 'PlayerState' : 'struct' type redefinition).

What is the best way to resolve this?

I have thought of:

- Renaming, but I will break the naming convention (and it really is the players 'state')
- Putting it in a namespace, but then I should put Every class in a namespace which means a Lot of work

Is there any other way (maybe a special MSVC 2010 vay) of say exclude that file or some sort of 'undefine' that enum or something else?

[edit] and the answer is, Loud and clear, NAMESPACES! +1 and thanks all!

Comment: weren't namespaces created to prevent problems like this?  Even though it would require more work I'd suggest doing that as it seems like the correct way forward.

Answer (score 7):

Namespace, that's what it's there for after all. Grouping and avoiding name collisions. It will not hurt if you go through your code base and put everything in a namespace. It's what you should've been doing all along already.

Answer (score 3):

> Putting it in a namespace, but then I should put Every class in a
>   namespace which means a Lot of work

Well, tough, basically. Classes should be in namespaces *anyway*. If you didn't put them in a namespace, then that's not sustainable, it's just cutting corners, and this is why.

Answer (score 2):

The obvious answer is : use a custom namespace for all your projects. It should have a unique name, and if you like even more depths of namespaces.

Answer (score 2):

I'd put it in a namespace.

No, that doesn't mean you need to put all classes in a namespace. Just say

```
using myns::PlayerState;
```

at the appropriate time, or if the conflict would still arise at that time,

```
typedef myns::PlayerState myPlayerState;
```

<sub>If you really want to go quick-and-dirty, do a</sub>

```
#define PlayerState MyPlayerState
```

*after* including `<windows.h>`